# Stacks algebraic over a given stack

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ct.category-theory, stacks, algebraic-stacks

Given a base site $S$ of schemes, consider a stack $\mathcal{C}$ on $S$ not assumed to be algebraic. Then in principle, given another stack $\mathcal{E}$ on $S$, together with a map of stacks $\mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{C}$ over $S$, we could ask for $\mathcal{E}$ to be *algebraic over $\mathcal{C}$*. This would entail, aside from having an appropriate surjective map from a scheme or algebraic space, demanding that $\mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{E} \times_{\mathcal{C}} \mathcal{E}$ was representable. At this point I'm being agnostic whether $\mathcal{E}$ is in fact a stack over $\mathcal{C}$, since the definition I give doesn't require this (and if $\mathcal{C}$ is not fibred in groupoids, which is conceivable, this is not always possible to organise).

Has this concept appeared in the literature? I cannot find anything about it in the [Stacks Project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/).

---

**EDIT** In the comments Ariyan Javanpeykar identifies this concept as a map of stacks being *representable by algebraic stacks*, which appears a few times in the literature without being formally defined and I guess must be a kind of folklore definition (it's not too difficult to guess, but I cannot find a paper that uses the phrase that also gives a definition). What I would like to use such a thing for is to look at geometric properties of maps of stacks that are representable by algebraic stacks, much as one can talk about geometric properties of maps that are representable (by schemes, or by algebraic spaces, even). It may be one gains nothing new, but it might allow for a more flexible definition in some cases.

Comment: If you like, this is kind of like asking whether $\mathcal{E}$ is 'relatively algebraic' over $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: I don't know if it already appeared in the literature, but I think @Emerton might be someone to ask about this, as his group at the Stacks project workshop might have worked on something related to this.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think he's active here anymore. If I get no response in a few days I'll ask directly (but I guess you know him better than me!)

Comment: @DavidRoberts Let $X\to Y$ be a morphism of categories fibred in groupoids over $(Sch/S)_{fppf}$ (with $S$ a scheme). The morphism $X\to Y$ is representable by algebraic stacks if, for any algebraic stack $Z$ over $S$ and any morphism $Z\to Y$, the fibre product $X\times_Y Z$ is an algebraic stack. Is this not the notion you're looking for? See TAG 04SX for the algebraic spaces version.

Comment: @Ariyan I'm not assuming my categories are fibred in groupoids, as that case is rather easy. There are plenty of stacks like that. But thanks for the terminology, it didn't occur to me.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar that seems like the kind of thing I'm after, however, Google returns only a handful of hits for the phrase "representable by algebraic stacks", and only three of those are in fact what you intend, and none of them give any sort of detailed treatment (or even define the notion). Is there a reference at all, or is the sort of thing that pbelmans was hinting would be included in the Stacks Project at some point?

Comment: Hmm, section 2.3 of http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~emerton/pdffiles/proper.pdf gives some clues for special cases...

Comment: @DavidRoberts The notion "representable by algebraic stacks" does not appear explicitly in the Stacks Project, as far as I know. [However, have a look at Tag 04YW for something similar, but unrelated.] The notion you are interested in is certainly very natural to consider, and it should appear implicitly in the literature. The only references I know are the paper by Emerton-Gee you just found, and this paper by Jason Starr http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.496.2582&rep=rep1&type=pdf See for instance Proposition 4.2 and its proof in loc. cit...cont'd below.

Comment: The way I see the relative notion of algebraicity being applied in Prop. 4.2 is somehow "the other way around" (than the one you're interested in) in the sense that $X_{pol}\to X_{pr, f,lpf}$ is a morphism of stacks which is representable by algebraic stacks, and $X_{pol}$ is (or turns out to be) an algebraic stack, but $X_{pr, f, lpf}$ isn't.